# How to use a HTTP HEAD request as health check for Marathon?

Tags: http, containers, marathon, health-monitoring

Look like the protocols `HTTP` or `MESOS_HTTP` only do `GET` request.

This works:

```
"healthChecks": [
  {
    "protocol": "COMMAND",
    "command": "curl -I http://0.0.0.0:5000/",
    "gracePeriodSeconds": 300,
    "intervalSeconds": 60,
    "timeoutSeconds": 20,
    "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3
  }
],
```

But I found it to much for such simple tasks... I would expect something simpler, something like `"method":"HEAD"`:

```
"healthChecks": [
  {
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "path": "/",
    "portIndex": 5000,
    "method": "HEAD",
    "gracePeriodSeconds": 300,
    "intervalSeconds": 60,
    "timeoutSeconds": 20,
    "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3
  }
],
```

Comment: That's correct but what is the question?

BTW, hi, long time no see ;)

Comment: I've just added a better explanation, @michael-hausenblas. Nice to see you around :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need/want HTTP `HEAD` based health checks then COMMAND-based are your only option. The HTTP-based support `GET` only. See also the [Marathon docs](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/health-checks.html) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i figured :-/